# How is this constant expression evaluated?

Tags: c, operators, language-lawyer, c11

when explaining constant expressions, the standard (well, draft [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) gives thi "enlightening" example:

> 118)
>   Thus, in the following initialization,
>       ***static int i = 2 || 1 / 0;***
>   the expression is a valid integer constant expression with value one.

*How is this expression evaluated?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logical or, `||` always returns either 0 or 1. First its left operand is evaluated, then, if the evaluation of the left operand resulted in 0, the right operand is evaluated and the value of the expression is 0 if the right operand also evaluates to 0, 1 otherwise. If the evaluation of the left operand resulted in a nonzero value, the entire expression evaluates to 1 without evaluating the right operand.

The precedence of the division operator `/` is higher than the precedence of the logical or, the expression

```
2 || 1 / 0
```

is implicitly parenthesized

```
2 || (1 / 0)
```

As an expression-tree:

```
     (||)
    /    \
   2     (/)
        /   \
       1     0
```

The precedence determines the shape of the tree, but the order of evaluation is independent from the precedence (except insofar as the precedence determines data-dependencies). For some operators (`||`, `&&`, `?:`, `,`), the order of evaluation of the operands is specified [and the right operands of `||` and `&&` aren't evaluated at all if the result is already determined after evaluation of the left operand, and of the second and third operands of `?:`, only one is evaluated - which one is determined by the evaluation of the first operand], generally the order of evaluation of the children of an operator-node is unspecified.

Since the left operand of `||` in

```
static int i = 2 || (1 / 0);
```

(the constant expression `2`) evaluates to a nonzero value, the evaluation of the expression stops there and the value of

```
2 || 1 / 0
```

is 1.

The evaluation of `||` is specified in section 6.5.14, paragraph 4:

> Unlike the bitwise `|` operator, the `||` operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation; if the second operand is evaluated, there is a sequence point between the evaluations of the first and second operands. **If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated**.

and its return value ibid, paragraph 3:

> The `||` operator shall yield 1 if either of its operands compare unequal to 0; otherwise, it yields 0. The result has type `int`.

Comment: But why is `||` evaluated before `/` ?

Comment: *For some operators (||, &&, ?:, ,), the order of evaluation of the operands is specified* - so this is it!

Comment: And in particular that the `1/0` isn't evaluated at all here. If it were evaluated, you'd probably get a compilation error (divide by zero).

Comment: @DanielFischer Precedence? In this particular case, it's more a question of sequence point.

Comment: @Morwenn Right, I misphrased that. Precedence determines the parentheses, but, as I said in the answer, not the order of evaluation.

Comment: So, am I getting too far generalizing that, when analyzing a complex expression one must 1) first determine the sequence points 2) then determine the precedence within each sub-expression (delimited from the others by sequence points) and 3) accept the fact that those sub-expressions are in most cases unsequenced in respect from one to another.

Comment: @Vorac You need the precedence to identify the subexpressions, so that goes first. 1) use the precedence to generate the expression-tree. 2) for each subtree with an operator node at the top (starting from the root of the entire tree), if that is an operator introducing a sequence point, evaluate the first operand to determine which, if any, of the other operands has to be evaluated, evaluate those if needed; if the operator doesn't introduce a sequence point, take your pick [you can, if you wish, interleave the evaluation of the operands then; if that matters: un(specified|defined) behaviour]